# Store a pointer to a non-specified size array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a function like this:

```
void Menu_show(uint8_t count, char items[][UI_COLS + 1]);
```

where *count* is the length of the first dimension of the array *items*.
I call this function in this way:

```
#define MAX_SIZE 4
char items[MAX_SIZE ][UI_COLS + 1];

for (uint8_t i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE ; i++) sprintf(items[i], "%u", i);
...
Menu_show(MAX_SIZE, items);
```

It works, but now I need to store a pointer to the first element of the array in my function.

My tougths:

1. the first element is `items[0][0]`
2. its pointer is `&items[0][0]`
3. but now I have a pointer to a char, not to a bidimensional array

In fact, something like `printf(items[3])` doesn't work in this way.
Then, I thought that the pointer to the first element of the second (fixed) dimension is `&item[0]` but:

```
char *_items[UI_COLS + 1];
_items = &items[0];
```

gives an error:

> assignment to expression with array type

I don't understand the right syntax to keep the bidimensional array usage when store the first location in a pointer.

Comment: What you present *shouldn't* work (correctly), and your compiler ought to be warning you about mismatched pointer types.  Specifically, the function parameter `items` has type `char (*)[UI_COLS]`, whereas the actual argument has type `char (*)[UI_COLS + 1]`.  These are not compatible, and the difference is significant.

Comment: You're talking about the first snippet? Indeed it works (avrgcc). Of course the two lines below don't work - as said. Ah ok, you're talking about the missing +1, fixed. Apologies.

Comment: Is this a code-dodging exercise that changes the code posted according to comments? Where is the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem?

Comment: It was a typo. I have a screenshot of my code. I cannot do copy-paste right now. Sorry, but the minimal code is there... I only need to store a pointer. How to improve my question?

Comment: I really don't understand the down-votes. There are plenty of very easy questions with a lot of votes, even without any piece of code. I'm just trying to learn from you experts.

Comment: @Mark. I don't understand votes either. I've only been on this site for a few weeks, but I've already noticed "easy" question and answers in other languages get up-voted, but similar C questions get downvoted. I wouldn't take it personally. I still learn in both cases -- which is why I'm on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you defined `_items` is as an array of `char *`.  You're attempting to assign to that array (which by itself is illegal) a pointer to an array.

Since each element of `items` is an array of type `char [UI_COLS + 1]`, you need to save its address in a pointer to an array:

```
char (*_items)[UI_COLS + 1] = &items[0];
printf("_items=%s\n", *_items);
```

Comment: Hence my mistake was the missing parenthesis around *_items*?

Comment: @Mark Correct.  The array subscript operator has higher precedence, so the parenthesis are required to make the address-of operator bind to the name first.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays can be interpreted as a pointer
If you have

```
arr[][]
```

arr can be considered

```
&arr[0]
```

and

```
arr[i]
```

can be considered as

```
&arr[i][0]
```

A two dimensional array doesn't really have a first element, except that it's first element array[0] is the first array in that twodimensional array.

```
printf(items[3]);
```

should work, because

```
items[3]
```

is a char array.

P.S.

For security reasons use

```
printf("%s",items[3]);
```

instead.